# Clearing multiple selects and check-boxes using onChange

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a form which has 3 select boxes, 8 check boxes and 1 text field.

The second and third select boxes are populated by the prior selection:
Select 1 fills select 2
select 2 fills select 3.

When I change select 2, select 3 will clear... PERFECT!
However, when I change select 1, only select 2 clears. Select 3 still has a value.

```
<html>
<select id="subject_select" name="subjects" class="chosen-select" data-    placeholder="Select a Subject" style="width:100%;font-size:.85em;" onchange="subject(this.value)">
<option></option>
<option value="1"></option>
<option> ...
</select>
<div id="subject"><select id="subjects_select" class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select a Grade" style="width:100%;font-size:.85em;" ></select></div>    
<div id="grade"><select id="standards_select" class="chosen-select" multiple data-placeholder="Select Standard(s)"></select></div>
```

My javascript is:

```
function subject(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    $("#subjects_select").chosen();
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","subject_get.php?subj="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```

I have tried using `document.getElementById('standards_select').value = "";`
and `function clear(val) {}` as welll as`onfocus="this.form.reset()"` all to no avail.

Can someone make a suggestion as to where I am going wrong? Please do not answer the question outright.

Comment: Could you add a working http://jsfiddle.net demo?

Comment: Sorry for hijacking this question's comments, but I wrote a cleaner answer to your now deleted question and was seconds away from submitting it: http://jsfiddle.net/6fgftL78/3/ hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @JasonSperske I deleted the question because it evidently did not belong there. Your solution is very much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think your example code is missing the relevant parts. However, you might be able to fix it by triggering the change event manually when there's a change for `subject`:

```
document.getElementById('standards_select').dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

This will additionally trigger your usual change listener for select 2 when select 1 is changed.

Comment: this did not work for me. However, using the same principle, I structured it as: `document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = "<select class='chosen-select' multiple></select> ";` and I am getting the desired results.